# Why does Spark crossJoin take so long for a tiny dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, cross-join

I'm trying to do the following crossJoin on two dataframes with 5 rows each, but Spark spawns 40000 tasks on my machine and it took 30 seconds to achieve the task. Any idea why that is happening?

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([['1','1'],['2','2'],['3','3'],['4','4'],['5','5']]).toDF('a','b')
df = df.repartition(1)

df.select('a').distinct().crossJoin(df.select('b').distinct()).count()
```

Comment: What # of partitions do you have? Too many partitions on too little data can make it slow

Comment: @KGS I have 1 partition for the tiny dataframe, but still it spawns a ton of tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call a `.distinct` before join, it requires a shuffle, so it repartitions data based on *spark.sql.shuffle.partitions* property value. Thus, `df.select('a').distinct()` and `df.select('b').distinct()` result in new DataFrames each with 200 partitions, 200 x 200 = 40000

Answer (score 1):

Two things - it looks like you cannot directly control the number of partitions a DF is created with, so we can first create a RDD instead (where you can specify the number of partitions) and convert it to DF. Also you can set the shuffle partitions to '1' as well. These both ensure you will have just 1 partition during the whole execution and should speed things up.

Just note that this shouldn't be an issue at all for larger datasets, for which Spark is designed (it would be faster to achieve the same result on a dataset of this size not using spark at all). So in the general case you won't really need to do stuff like this, but tune the number of partitions to your resources/data.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.default.parallelism", "1")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "1")

df = sc.parallelize([['1','1'],['2','2'],['3','3'],['4','4'],['5','5']], 1).toDF(['a','b'])
df.select('a').distinct().crossJoin(df.select('b').distinct()).count()
```

`spark.conf.set` sets the configuration for a single execution only, if you want more permanent changes do them in the actual spark conf file